# How to change line color in jspdf?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

How to change the color of line, produced by using `line(x1, y1, x2, y2)` method?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looks like it is possible to accomplish this using `setDrawColor()` function.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setDrawColor(255, 0, 0);
doc.line(35, 30, 100, 30);

doc.save('line.pdf');
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/YevgenyB/xsoaqyfj/)

UPD: if you add new page to document, you need to run `setDrawColor()` function again. Otherwise the color on the new page will be default black.

Answer (score 2):

You must call the setDrawColor function before the line function. For example:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setDrawColor(255,0,0);  // draw red lines
doc.line(100, 20, 100, 60);
doc.save('Red_line.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the **setDrawColor** function from the **jsPDF**.
This example definitely helps you

```
var pdf = new jsPDF();
pdf.setDrawColor("#096dd9");

//horizontal line
pdf.setLineWidth(0.2)
pdf.line(2, 25, 555, 25);

//vertical line
pdf.line(30, 2, 30, 100);
```